# Attempting to Uninstall a Program with a Batch file

Tags: batch-file, uninstallation

I am trying to uninstall a program using a batch file. I looked at a previously posted question from about 3 years ago using a variation of this:

```
wmic product where name="VIPRE Business Agent" call uninstall
```

While it appears to be working, the script runs and returns a successful reply, the program isn't uninstalling. What am I doing wrong or am I using the script wrong?

I know there is another question exactly like this, it's mine, and I am am trying to have it deleted since it started out completely different. I should have closed it first and then opened this one.

Here is the output from when the batch is ran:

```
E:\>echo off

E:\>wmic product where name="VIPRE Business Agent" call uninstall
Executing (\\DC-30026\ROOT\CIMV2:Win32_Product.IdentifyingNumber=" {56CA3334-8B72-48D1-81E7-3EF5243E45D5}",Name="VIPRE Business Agent",Version="7.5.5841")->Uninstall()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ReturnValue = 1603;
};
```

Edit Addition:
I finally got the batch to uninstall Vipre. But it still leaves behind the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Vipre Business Agent w\ a deployment folder and a config folder. How can I get a total uninstall?

Comment: Using that method you may find that the program is actually uninstalled, but the uninstall string is not removed from the registry. Try going to programs and features and uninstalling it after you run you batch. I think it will give you an error indicating that it failed to complete the installation. Post back if that is the case and we can try another way. Or you can find the uninstall key in HKLM\SOFTWARE\<Wow6432Node\>Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall and delete it. If you used InstallShield it will be under InstallShield Uninstall Information.

Comment: Awesome thank you. I will give it a shot and post back.

Comment: @RGuggisberg I tried what you suggested. I ran the batch file, it returned a successful uninstall. first and then went to the programs and features and selected Vipre for uninstall. It ran the uninstall without any errors. Why is the batch file saying it was successful with the uninstall yet the program still needs to be uninstalled manually?

Comment: Turn echo on (at least for the WMIC line above) and see what you get for output from that command.

Comment: @RGuggisberg I added the output to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this was a 32 bit app installed with InstallShield use this command:
C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information[YourUninstallProductCodeGoesHere]\Setup.exe

Comment: How do I add the to a batch file I can run in mass over another program?

Comment: Assuming this is a 32 bit app. First use Windows Explorer to verify that you have a Setup.exe file in C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{56CA3334-8B72-48D1-81E7-3EF5243E45D5}. If you do, then add this line including quotes to your bat file: "C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield Installation Information\{56CA3334-8B72-48D1-81E7-3EF5243E45D5}\Setup.exe" -uninst

Comment: Now I get "The system cannot find the path specified" as a response

Comment: Does the Setup.exe exist at that location? May be better to copy paste location from Windows Explorer bar. Did you use quotes around the filespec as shown?

Comment: I adjusted the path to reflect better that actual path to the setup file and I did add the command with the quote's. It displays the command as it runs it but doesn't display any output and the program still isn't uninstalled.

Comment: I finally got the batch to uninstall the Vipre. But it still leaves behind the folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Vipre Business Agent w\ a deployment folder and a config folder. How can I get a total uninstall?

Comment: Most likely those are folders/files that were modified post install. Since the installer did not put them there it will not remove them. If you are using InstallShield you can add things to the 'RemoveFile' table found under 'Additional Tools', 'Direct Editor'. But that will only work going forward for uninstalling apps installed with your new installer. For packages already installed you can add some RMDIR or DEL statements to your bat file. Something like IF EXIST <YourFolder> RMDIR /S /Q <YourFolder>